# Remove null variables from url

Tags: php, html

I have this form, when I press the submit button i will get redirected to select.inc.php.
But sometimes I dont want to fill out every field of the form but all the "variables"(?) are still getting appended to the URL.
When I only enter an id and will press the button the url will look like this: `localhost/inc/select.inc.php?id=1?username=?email=?password=?rank=`.

What I want is this: `localhost/inc/select.inc.php?id=1`

```
<form action="inc/select.inc.php" method="GET">
<h1 id="h1-select">Select</h1>
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Id">
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
</div>
<div class="row">                        
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" name="rank" placeholder="Rank">
</div>
<div class="row">
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Select</button>
</div>
</form>
```

I want this to show stuff from the MySQL database on a page like when I want to list all users with the rank "1".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all empty strings (you get them as empty strings, not null), you can run `$_GET` through [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$_GET = array_filter($_GET, function ($val) {
    return $val !== '';
});
```

Now the `$_GET`-param will only contain non empty strings.

If you don't need to keep `0` either, you can just do:

```
$_GET = array_filter($_GET);
```

That removes any param where the value is [falsy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: I tried it and I understand what it does, but sadly it does not remove the strings from the url.

Comment: Then either the fields aren't empty, or you've implemented it wrong. This should be placed in the top of your `select.inc.php`. Here's a demo of it in action: https://3v4l.org/unm8S